# Bind Angular com Canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

Bom dia gostaria saber se é possível fazer bind e/ou forçar o bind do angular com o canvas. O meu problema é o seguinte:

Eu estou a utilizar o canvas para dar uma representação gráfica ao meu cliente e para UI estou a utilizar angular 1.6.2, mas sempre que faço um evento de clique associado com o canvas actualizo a variável (ex: `marcado: true`):

```
[
    {
    "numero": 1,
    "x": 205,
    "y": 23,
    "marcado": false,
    "descricao": ["a", "b"]
    },
    {
    "numero": 2,
    "x": 502,
    "y": 22,
    "marcado": false,
    "descricao": []
    }
]
```

É possível forçar o bind dentro desta função?

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', function () {
            handlePontosColission(mousePos);
            n++;
            console.log("X " + mousePos.x + " Y " + mousePos.y);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o meu problema adicionando `$scope.$digest()` sempre que preciso de actualizar as variáveis.